# List<T> with different values types

Tags: c#

C#. 
I have a class:

```
public class SQLValue<T> 
{ 
    public string nam { get; set; } 
    public string typ { get; set; } 
    public T val      { get; set; } 
}
```

now I want to create

```
List<SQLValue> lst = List<SQLValue>();
```

and add elements to it like that:

```
lst.Add(new List<SQLValue>(nam = "PlayerName", typ = "string", val = "Bot1"));
lst.Add(new List<SQLValue>(nam = "Ally", typ = "bool", val = true));
lst.Add(new List<SQLValue>(nam = "Levl", typ = "int",  val = 2));
```

so I want to have a list of class that contain the value val with different types. Is it real?

Comment: try using `dynamic` as the generic type

Comment: How is `lst` used ?

Comment: @Spotted This is a very important question. I'm thinking maybe the OP wants to mimic the way that you get types and values out of a [`SqlDataReader.Item[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y64yaah2(v=vs.110).aspx), but would like to know for sure.

Comment: Would you want something that can be somehow `List<T1, T2>`?

Comment: Also, is there always going to be the same amount of items for each type. Like if it had 5 `int`s, there would also be 5 `string`s and 5 `T`s?

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Some base type is required. Obviously, you can always use `List<object>`,
if you just want to store `SQLValue<T>` instances.

But, assuming, that you want to *process* list items depending on `nam` and `typ` properties, all you can do here is to extract some base class/interface:

```
public interface ISQLValue
{
    public string nam { get; set; } 
    public string typ { get; set; } 
    public object val { get; set; }
}
```

implement it in `SQLValue<T>` this way:

```
public class SQLValue<T> : ISQLValue
{ 
    public string nam { get; set; } 
    public string typ { get; set; } 

    public T val { get; set; } 

    object ISQLValue.val 
    {  
        get { return this.val; }
        set { this.val = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

and use `List<ISQLValue>` to store instances and process them:

```
var sqlValues = new List<ISQLValue>
{
    new SQLValue<string> { nam="PlayerName", typ="string", val="Bot1" }
    new SQLValue<bool> { nam="Ally", typ="bool", val=true }
    new SQLValue<int> { nam="Levl", typ="int", val=2 }
};

foreach (var value in sqlValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"nam = {value.name}, typ = {value.typ}, val = {value.val}");
}
```

That is, in case of some batch processing, `ISQLValue` will be used. But if you know `T` of particular `ISQLValue`, you can cast it to `SQLValue<T>` and use `T val` instead of `object val`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, because generics are eventually converted into separate types.

> When a generic type is first constructed with a value type as a parameter, the runtime creates a **specialized generic type** with the supplied parameter or parameters substituted in the appropriate locations in the MSIL. **Specialized generic types are created one time for each unique value type that is used as a parameter**.
>
> <sub>Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time</sub>

So `SQLValue<int>` and `SQLValue<bool>` are really two different types. As a result, you can't create a `List<T>` with,

```
var lst = new List<SQLValue>();
```

Instead, you have to specify the type `T` for `SQLValue` as well. So something like this would be allowed,

```
var lst = new List<SQLValue<bool>>();
```

Or,

```
var lst = new List<SQLValue<int>>();
```

---

Also, the syntax for adding elements to such a list is incorrect in your code. For example, if you are working with a list,

```
var lst = new List<SQLValue<bool>>();
```

You can add values to it using:

```
lst.Add(new SQLValue<bool> {  nam="Ally", typ="bool", val=true });
```

Or, through the constructor, if you have defined one,

```
lst.Add(new SQLValue<bool> ("Ally", "bool", true ));
```

where the constructor could be:

```
public SQLValue(string nam, string typ, T val )
{
    this.nam = nam;
    this.typ = typ;
    this.val = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class, which will hold all that information:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type PropType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

then you can add items into it:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass(){ Name = "name1", PropType = typeof(string), Value = "asdasd" },
    new MyClass(){ Name = "name2", PropType = typeof(bool), Value = true },
    new MyClass(){ Name = "name3", PropType = typeof(int), Value = 11 },

};
```

and then use it for example like this:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(item.PropType))
    {
        case TypeCode.String:
            break;
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            break;
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: As much as this solution smells, I believe this is the appropriate answer for this question. I appreciate that c# has much more sophisticated tools like `dynamic` and generics, but sometimes you just need an object!  (All that being said, I think the design that led to the OP's question is suspect.)

Comment: I was hoping some comments or more details from OP, to know more about what he actually want to achieve, cause it's kind of XY problem. But anyway, I tried to give him some alternative ideas, maybe he will notice his problem by himself.